# Minimum wage in an international payroll context

Tags: limited-liability-company, international, private-company, payroll

Suppose a UK private limited company is hiring an employee from an EU country. The employee is hired as an actual full-time employee, i.e. not as a freelancer or as a consultant.

Does the UK company need to abide by the minimum wage laws of both the UK and the EU country's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The employer needs to abide by the labor laws of every country where it has employees. So if the UK company has employees in the UK and in that other EU country then yes, it needs to abide by the minimum wage laws of both, and to each employee with respect to that employee's local laws. I.e.: French, for example, employee will get the French minimum wage, and the UK employee will get the UK minimum wage.

Note that it's not just wages. The UK company has to abide by *all* the labor laws in that EU country with regard to that local employee.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's super helpful. But am I correct that the UK company won't have to follow up the UK minimum wage for the French employee? I.e. is it fine if the wage is below the UK minimum but higher than the French minimum?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg you'd probably want to run it by a lawyer, but that would be my understanding